# Image Segmentation, watershed, waterfall, p algorithm

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, imagej, waterfall, watershed

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any currently available packages for segmentation using the waterfall method or p algorithm. I've looked in github, CRAN, and Fiji and haven't found anything despite published literature discussing the benefits of waterfall and the P algorithm methods going back to 2009. Right now I'm using watershed segmentation on some images but keep running into problems with oversegmentation and it seems like these other two methods might solve some of these issues.

Edit: Here are some of the papers I was referencing:

- [Serge Beucher: "Watershed, Hierarchical Segmentation and Waterfall Algorithm"](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-011-1040-2_10) (Springer, fee required)
- [BEUCHER, MARCOTEGUI: P algorithm, a dramatic enhancement of the waterfall transformation](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/publi/P-Algorithm_SB_BM.pdf)

Comment: Could you maybe add some references to the published methods please?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any implementation for these. I guess the corresponding message (http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Mean-Free-Path-and-Waterfall-or-P-Algorithm-Segmentation-td5012341.html) on the ImageJ mailing list was done by you, right? Otherwise, I'd suggest asking there...

Comment: Are you aware of the http://fiji.sc/Morphological_Segmentation plugin? It might at least go into the right direction for you...

Comment: You're right on both counts. I've been using the morphological segmentation and its alright but I was still hoping for something better. There is this HSEG tool from NASA which looks promising but so far that's as close as I've gotten.; opensource.gsfc.nasa.gov/projects/HSEG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, an answer regarding the Hierarchical segmentation was posted on the ImageJ mailing list by [Ignacio Arganda-Carreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496821/ignacio-arganda-carreras). He implemented it on an experimental branch of [MorphoLibJ](https://github.com/ijpb/MorphoLibJ/tree/waterfalls).

All credits go to Ignacio!

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, as mentioned by Serge Beucher in his paper "Towards a unification of waterfalls, standard and P algorithms" all source codes for : enhanced waterfalls, standard hierarchy and P algorithm are available in mamba-image library. See here [github](https://github.com/nicolasBeucher/mamba-image) or here [mamba-image.org](http://www.mamba-image.org/)